# draw graphics outside of paint method

Tags: java, graphics, awt

```
private void draw_shape() {                                         
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
    repaint();
}
```

In paint method only those graphics are drawn which is a part of paint method because of which
I wanted to draw shapes outside of paint method. 
This code draws the line but it immediately disappeares, I don't understand why this is happening. please help

Comment: Problem is more likely to be in getGraphics or repaint, and you can't be outside of paint...

Comment: BTW - is this using Swing or AWT components?

Answer (score 3):

This doens't work because you are getting the current `Graphics` outside of the [Swing repaint thread](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html). Basically:

- you get the current `Graphics`
- you draw something on it
- then you call `repaint()` that will call the `paint()` of the component thus discarding all you did

To make it work you should override the `paint` (`paintComponent` for Swing) method of your object:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g); // if you have children to the component
  g.drawLine(..)
}
```

and then just call `repaint()` when something has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

The line disappears because Swing (or AWT) will call paint(Graphics) or paintComponent(Graphics g) in order to pain the component.

What you need to do is to put your drawing logic on the paint(Graphics) or paintComponent(Graphics g) method. The latter is more advisable.

If you really need to draw things using another method, store an image as a class field and draw this image on the paint or paintComponent methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `paint` method also paints stuff. You should not draw graphics outside the paint method. You should instead override the paint method, like this:

```
@Override public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help found the answer

```
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) createImage(300, 300);
image.getGraphics().drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300);
jLabel1.setIcon( new ImageIcon(image ));
```